# Laravel dependency injection on entity object

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, domain-driven-design, inversion-of-control

Im trying to get the following working:
Im using the laravel framework and the service provider to inject dependencies.
I created a Session object and a Session interface, the session object implements the session interface. I did this because i dont want to couple the session to a specific framework implementation (in this case laravel).

I also have a entity object X, this object needs the session for getting some data out of it. In the constructor it has the ISession, this would mean it would be injected by the IOC. But i also need to create these entity objects with the new operator. This would mean that i need to pass the implementation of the session. How can i avoid this ? I could use App::make(), but this would mean that i have laravel coupled to my entity object.

Comment: Instead of new Entity make yourself an EntityFactory defined in your ioc and use it for creating new entities.  But I got to say that whole idea of making your entities depend on session objects is a bit of a red flag.  And how realistic is it to expect that you might actually swap out a session object from a completely different library?

Comment: I will take a look at the entity factory. The chance that it will be swapped out isnt that big, but you never know what happens. For that reason i dont want to couple my value objects with framework related things. If i would do that then i dont need the session interface because i can use the laravel session facade directly. Anyways thank you for youre comment, i will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the binding on the IoC container is to avoid using the `new` operator everytime you need to create a new instance

So, you have to make the binding between the interface and the implementation you want, and then use:

```
$session = App::make('ISession');
```

to get the implementation you have binded to the interface.

Yes, you'll have your Laravel container coupled to your application, but Laravel IS your application

Comment: Im using the DDD principal, using the above solution would mean that i have laravel implementation in my domain logic.

Comment: But your entities are part of your domain logic are they not?  And you want the domain to be aware of a session?  Just does not sound right.

Comment: I agree with that, but i dont feel comfortable with the fact that i couple domain logic with laravel by using the App::make() inside of an entity object.

Answer (score 0):

On Laravel all my interfaces are resolved through a Service Provider, where I bind the Session interface to a certain implementation.

Like:

```
$this->app->bind('session-interface-namespace', function(){return SessionImplementation()})
```

Once I do it, all the classes requiring the Session interface will resolve my Session implementation as their "real" dependency. With that, my business/domain logic it's separated from my, let's call it like that, infrastructure logic.

The next step I would do is an entity factory.

Hope it helps,